# Can I "map" an "OF" over a list of lemmas

Tags: dictionary, isabelle, isar

I just wrote this code:

```
lemmas gc_step_intros =
  normal[OF step.intros(1)] normal[OF step.intros(2)] normal[OF step.intros(3)]
  normal[OF step.intros(4)] normal[OF step.intros(5)] drop
```

where `step.intros` really only has 5 lemmas. Is there a convenient way to avoid this repetition, i.e. something that might look like the following?

```
lemmas gc_step_intros = normal[OF_EACH step.intros] drop
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use `THEN` instead of `OF` and exploit the fact that an attribute is applied to all theorems in a list of theorems. The following should do what you want:

```
lemmas gc_step_intros = step.intros[THEN normal] drop
```